# Ms-Access Open a Query Sourced from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which takes some parameters and returns records. The front end application is MS Access 2003. I have a form with some filter controls and an execute button.

When a user clicks the button, I want my VBA code to call the stored procedure with the provided parameters and then display the results in a grid using `Docmd.OpenQuery` or `Docmd.OpenTable`.

Currently, I'm using a pass-through query to open a recordset with the results of the stored procedure, then looping through the recordset to insert each record into a temporary table, which I then open using `DoCmd.OpenTable`.

This seems unnecessarily complicated. I would like to avoid the temporary table completely and simply display the records in a grid using `DoCmd.OpenQuery` if possible. If that is not possible, I would like to find a way to insert the records from the recordset into the temp table in a single step, instead of looping the recordset.

EDIT:
I had previously tried opening the pass-through query using DoCmd.OpenQuery as suggested, but had received "Run time error 3270 - Property not found" when the DoCmd.OpenQuery line was executed.  This led me to believe that opening the pass through directly was not possible.  Here is a snippet of that version of my code:

```
sql = "EXEC dbo.rptContractorBidSummary " & IIf(frmClosedProjectWindow.Value = 1, "1", IIf(frmClosedProjectWindow.Value = 2, "2", "NULL"))
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryContractorBidSummary")
qdef.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & Cconst.SERVER_NAME & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
qdef.sql = sql
qdef.ODBCTimeout = 1000
qdef.ReturnsRecords = True
Set qdef = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryContractorBidSummary"
```

EDIT:
I was finally able to get this approach to work.  The code is fine.  The problem turned out to be that I had not set the permissions on the stored procedure correctly in the back end.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to open a saved pass-through query with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`. If you need to specify parameter values before opening the query you could modify the `.SQL` property of its QueryDef object, e.g., something like this (untested):

```vbs
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("yourPassThroughQuery")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC yourStoredProcedure " & yourParameterValue
Set qdf = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "yourPassThroughQuery"
```

Comment: Thanks!   This is actually the first thing I tried, but I received 'Run time error 3270 - Property not found', which led me to believe that this approach was not possible.  Here's a snippet of my code:
`code`

Comment: @DowDrake: What exact line gives this error? Please add it to your question.

Comment: The error is raised in the DoCmd.OpenQuery line.  Here's a snippet of my code:

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryContractorBidSummary")
    qdef.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & Cconst.SERVER_NAME & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" &  stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
    qdef.sql = sql
    qdef.ODBCTimeout = 1000
    qdef.ReturnsRecords = True
    Set qdef = Nothing
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryContractorBidSummary"

Comment: @DowDrake Please [edit] your question to include additional information instead of burying it in the comments to an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly snippet, I inserted 4-spaces before each code line, but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just open the passthru with `docmd.openquery` ?? I use that regularly. You can also set the passthru as the source of a form or a report.  Just before calling it you alter its `.SQL` to match your criteria.